# How can I create a Road Side Unit and an eNodeB in a ns2 scenario

Tags: ns2, lte, 802.11p

I have an 802.11p scenario with some nodes that already have a sumo trajectory, Right now I'm testing the V2V (vehicle to vehicle) communication measuring the throughout with DSDV and AODV routing protocols but I also need to add at least 3 802.11p RSU (Road side unit) and an LTE eNodeB, how can I add those 2 network elements to my ns2 project to be able to test the V2I (vehicle to infrastructure) communication.

Answer (score 0):

> LTE eNodeB

One of the "LTE source code packages" available from the now closed 'googlecode' was "minerve-mampaka-lte" : Has some files not found elsewhere : Parameters.tcl, Topology.tcl, main.tcl ...

LTE__minerve-mampaka-lte.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xpqUxUV3d1WHKZsBS54r_Qnx-IfOj3HB/view?usp=sharing

From the simulation `main.tcl`

```
#include other tcl files
source Parameters.tcl
source Topology.tcl
source session-rtp.tcl
source http-agent.tcl
source http-cache.tcl
source http-server.tcl
```

From the configuration file Topology.tcl, lines 53 - 70 :

```
#create dual-simplex links between eNodeB and the SGW
#uplink S1-U link from each eNB to SGW with user defined bandwidth and delay 
$ns simplex-link $eNodeB $SGW $input_(UP_S1_BANDWIDTH) $input_(UP_S1_DELAY) $input_(UP_S1_QUEUE)
$ns queue-limit $eNodeB $SGW $input_(QUEUE_LIMIT)

#downlink S1-U link from each SGW to eNB with user defined bandwidth and delay 
$ns simplex-link $SGW $eNodeB $input_(DOWN_S1_BANDWIDTH) $input_(DOWN_S1_DELAY) $input_(DOWN_S1_QUEUE)
$ns queue-limit $SGW $eNodeB $input_(QUEUE_LIMIT)

#create duplex link between SGW and PGW with user defined bandwidth and delay 
$ns duplex-link $SGW $PGW $input_(S5_BANDWIDTH) $input_(S5_DELAY) $input_(S5_QUEUE)
$ns queue-limit $SGW $PGW $input_(QUEUE_LIMIT)

#create duplex link between PGW and SERVER with user defined bandwidth and delay 
$ns duplex-link $PGW $SERVER $input_(SGI_BANDWIDTH) $input_(SGI_DELAY) $input_(SGI_QUEUE)
$ns queue-limit $PGW $SERVER $input_(QUEUE_LIMIT)

}
```

Example, using : Include ' Topology.tcl' in your simulation → `source Topology.tcl`

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen I will give it  look, but can you explain me how can I implement it in my project I don't see how I can integrate those files or lines into my project and also if you have some advice for the implementation of the 802.11p Road side units or access points to form the vehicle to infraestructure communication I will be more than thankful